# Check if a complete type is created from a type constructor

Tags: d

I want to check if some complete type is created from a type constructor for example in C++ I can do

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct is_vector{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
template<class A,class B>
struct is_vector<std::vector<A,B>>{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
int main(){
    int i;
    std::vector<int> iv;
    std::cout << is_vector<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_vector<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want to the same thing in D

```
struct ShaderType(T,string s){
  alias Type = T;
  enum string stringType = s;
}
template isShaderType(T){
  enum isShaderType = false;
}
template isShaderType(A,string s, T: ShaderType!(A,s) ){
  enum isShaderType = true;
}

void main(){
  writeln(isShaderType!(ShaderType!(int,"int")));
}
```

Sadly this prints false and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicit template parameters go at the end of the list in D:

```
template isShaderType(T: ShaderType!(A,s), A, string s){
```

Also have a look at [`std.traits.isInstanceOf`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#isInstanceOf).